# Getting AutoIncrement value after saving in Spring

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm working with Spring Boot 2 (Hibernate, JPA) and MySQL. I need a unique, auto increment custom reference number, for example **18/10/5** (here, 18 is year, 10 is month, 5 is auto increment field). The strategy I used is:

Create an auto increment field. Get the value of auto increment after saving and joining with `yy/MM/`.

*I removed unwanted annotations for easiness.*

**Model class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="account")
public class Account{
    @Id
    private String id;
    
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long autoIncrement;
    
    String refNo;
    
    //Other fields, Constructors, Getters And Setters
}
```

Then in the controller, first I save, then I get the id of the saved object and trying to update

**Controller class**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/account")
public class AccountController {

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public ModelAndView saveAccount(@ModelAttribute("account") Account account){
        //few codes
        accountService.save(account) //Saving
        
        accountService.updateRefNo(account.getId()) //try to update
    }
}
```

**Service class**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService{

    @Autowired
    AccountRepository accountRepository;
    
    //Few methods
    
    public void updateRefNo(String id) {        
        Account account=findById(id); // return the object
        
        String year = // getting year
        String month = //getting month
        
        account.setRefNo(year+"/"+month+"/"+account.getAutoIncrement());
    }
}
```

Data is saved. When I try to update, `account.getAutoIncrement()` returns **null**, but its saved in the database. I tried `saveAndFlush()` also. Why does this happen? Not committed?

Comment: Is the account a new one ? And is the id of the account provided by the client? The code I normally see generates the id when saving. If this is also true for your code, don´t you call your updateRefNo method with null since you don´t use the returned id from saving?

Answer (score 0):

in your `updateRefNo` I dont see save or update call on `Account` entity

```
public void updateRefNo(String id) {        
    Account account=findById(id); // return the object

    String year = // getting year
    String month = //getting month

    account.setRefNo(year+"/"+month+"/"+account.getAutoIncrement());

    // update in DB
    accountRepository.save(account);  or accountRepository.update(account);
}
```

Comment: Since I use `@Transactional`, hopefully no need to create a new call/method

Comment: What has @Transaction to do with save/update.  its for different purpose ??  Can you add your accountService.save method. I want to see how you are saving detail

Comment: only save method `accountRepository.save(account)` . I read some tutorials, we don't need to specify any method if we use `@Transactional`, this annotation always does transaction with db, so no need to call any method.,  And this is the second problem, But first is `findById(id)` returns null of `account.getAutoIncrement()`

Comment: @MyTwoCents `@Transactional` doesn't need any specific method to save or update. Automatically it saves.